Naming of Mendeleev’s predicted elements- ekaboron and ekaaluminium
I’m studying the evolution of the periodic table as part of my school syllabus(CBSE class 11th). I have a doubt in the naming of predicted elements in Dmitri Mendeleev’s periodic table:
From what I’ve been taught and understood, the gaps in his table represented as of yet undiscovered elements. To name them we put the prefix “eka” on the element’s name directly above its position. It is easy to see this for elements like ekamanganese (Technetium), ekadilicon (Germanium)..
However, ekaboron and ekaaluminium (scsndium and gallium respectively) are still confusing

In the modern periodic table, it is easy to justify gallium’s designation of eka-aluminium, but scandium’s designation isn’t evident.
In the Mendeleev’s periodic table I have seen, scandium comes in between aluminium and gallium. This doesn’t justify any of their designations by Mendeleev.


Can someone please give a justification for the names eka-boron for scandium and eka-aluminium for gallium?
Secondary question- I’ve seen many versions of Mendeleev’s periodic table. One version has the elements in the groups staggered in alternating pattern. Another version doesn’t have this. Yet another version builds upon the first  version by adding “A” and “B” subgrouping. Which one of these is the original table?
(First one-staggered version, next a/B subgrouping version, next unstaggered version)



Thanks!

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125276/structure-of-the-periodic-table https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135144/why-there-is-no-position-of-h-and-he-in-lothar-meyers-curve

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#History - Mendeleev’s "periodic table" was more of a list.

The prefix "eka" means "after" in the old language "sanskrit". As he was from Russian origin, Mendeleev refused to use (latin or) greek letters and (latin or) greek prefixes like "meta" to translate "after". He preferred to go back to another old language. And he chose sanskrit, because sanskrit has an aryan origin, like Russian.

If I understand it correctly, the OP does not ask why eka- prefix was  used, but why it was used that way for the particular elements.

And for Mendeleev's original handwritten periodic table, here it is: https://physicsworld.com/a/an-unelementary-affair-150-years-of-the-periodic-table/

From my dictionary, sanskrit is an indo-aryan language, that was the literary language in old India.

Russian and other Slavic languages are not indo-aryan!

eka does not mean "after"...in most South Asian language ek or eka implies "one".
